# Show that ${C_\infty }/\left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle \simeq {C_n}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let ${C_\infty } = \left\langle c \right\rangle $ be an infinite
>    cyclic group. Show that if $n > 0$, then $${C_\infty }/\left\langle
>  {{c^n}} \right\rangle  \simeq {C_n}$$where ${C_n}$ is a finite cyclic
>    group with $n$ elements.

**My work**

Let $f:{C_\infty } \to {C_n}$ is defined by $f({c^k}) = {b^{k\,\bmod \,n}}$, where ${C_n} = \left\langle b \right\rangle {\text{ and }}{c^k} \in {C_\infty }$. We want to show that $f$ - is a homomorphism and $\left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle  = {\text{Ker}}(f)$.

Let ${c^k},\,\,{c^l} \in {C_\infty }$, then $f({c^k}{c^l}) = f({c^{k + l}}) = {b^{(k + l)\,\bmod \,n}} = {b^{k\,\bmod \,n}}{b^{l\,\bmod \,n}} = f({c^k})f({c^l})$. Hence, $f$ is a homomorphism.

We claim that $\left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle  = {\text{Ker}}(f)$. If ${c^{kn}} \in \left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle $, then we have $f({c^{kn}}) = {b^{kn\,\bmod \,n}} = {b^0} = e$.

Conversely, if ${c^a} \in {\text{Ker}}(f) \Rightarrow f({c^a}) = e$. So, ${b^{a\,\bmod \,n}} = {b^0} \Rightarrow a = kn \Rightarrow {c^a} \in \left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle $. Clearly, ${\text{Im}}(f) = {C_n}$ and therefore ${C_\infty }/\left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle  \simeq {C_n}$.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the first isomorphism theorem for groups.  You also need to show that $f$ is surjective.  I'd probably also say $(k+l) \mod n$ instead of $k + l \mod n$ just to make it clear that the mod applies to the sum and not just $l$.  Granted it's clear from context, but still..

Comment: @tilper I used the following fact: "If $f:G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $G/{\text{Ker}}(f) \simeq {\text{Im}}(f)$". I don't think i need to show that $f$ is surjective... I showed that $f$ is a homom. then i showed that ${\text{Ker}}(f) = \left\langle {{c^n}} \right\rangle $ and it is clear that ${\text{Im}}(f) = {C_n}$

Comment: Right, I missed the $\text{Im}(f) = C_n$.  That works, as long as you can get away with saying $\text{Im}(f) = C_n$ is clear!

Comment: You haven't specified that $b$ generates $C_n$; it looks like you have chosen an arbitrary element $b\in C_n.$

Comment: @ByronSchmuland right, added this detail.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite cyclic group is $\Bbb Z$. It has $$\langle c\mid\rangle$$ as a presentation, since it is free.

If we introduce the relator $nc$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, then we get the presentation $$\langle c\mid nc\rangle,\tag{$\mathcal{P}$}$$ which defines $\Bbb Z_n$.$\dagger$

But we get from the presentation of $\Bbb Z$ above to $(\mathcal{P})$ by "killing" $nc $; that is, by quotienting out by the normal subgroup $\langle nc\rangle$, which is where you are. The result then follows from the first isomorphism theorem, by setting the kernel of some homomorpism equal to that normal subgroup.

This is a little cobbled together but I hope it helps :)

---

$\dagger$ I'm using additive notation here, so $c^n\leftrightsquigarrow nc$.

Comment: Urgh; if you are going to use $\mathbb{Z}$ to represent the infinite cyclic group, then at least have the decency to use additive notation for it, not multiplicative one....

Comment: Is that better, @ArturoMagidin?

Comment: Yes, that is better. It’s perverse to both use $\mathbb{Z}$ for the infinite cyclic group *and* use multiplciative notation, given that $\mathbb{Z}$ has a multiplcation... which doesn’t turn it into a group, but rather a free monoid of infinite rank with a zero adjoined.